# Is there a simple method for making young tableau without special packages?

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays

I don't mind if my young tableau are not perfect. I have no idea how to install packages at the moment. I just want to write something simple regarding the symmetric group on three objects. I'm thinking that maybe something using tables, arrays or matrices might look acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can always use the built in `picture` construction from LaTeX:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
\newcommand{\ybox}{\picture(1,1)
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){1}\line(1,0){1}}
\put(1,0){\line(0,1){1}}
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){1}}
\endpicture}

\newcommand{\ylabel}[1]{\makebox(1,1){#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{picture}(2,2)
  \put(0,0){\ybox}
  \put(0,1){\ybox}
  \put(1,1){\ybox}
\end{picture}
\end{displaymath}
Some text and text and text and text and text and text and text and
text and text and text and text and text and text and text and text. 
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{picture}(3,3)
  \put(0,0){\ybox}
  \put(0,1){\ybox}
  \put(0,2){\ybox}
  \put(1,2){\ybox}
  \put(2,2){\ybox}
  \put(0,2){\ylabel{a}}
\end{picture}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

In the above I have set the `\unitlength` to fix the size of the unit coordinate vectors.  I then defined a command `\ybox` that produces a square box of side one.  This can then be placed in a `picture` at an arbitrary position `(x,y)` via `\put(x,y){\ybox}`.  The origin of the coordinate system is the lower left corner.  The picture is enclosed in `\picture(a,b)...\endpicture` where `a` is the total number of columns and `b` the total number of rows.  Finally I have added a command `\ylabel` for placing labels in a given box.  Note that large labels will require you to increase `\unitlength` so there is enough space.

Answer (score 5):

Not the answer you asked , but I hope that put some light in the true trouble: Do not know how install a LaTeX package is not an excuse to reinvent the wheel, but to learn how install packages. Compare the simplicity of this example with making it from the scratch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\begin{ytableau}
a & d & f \\
b & c \\
c
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Moreover, probably you do not need to know how install a package to make a Young tableau, since the `ytableau` package most probably is *already installed* in your hard disk (exist in both TeX Live and MikTeX distributions).  So, just try the above example before asking for troubles.

Comment: Thanks! It works.  I came across other packages somehow. There seem to be about 100 different ways to do the same thing in Tex. This was very helpful.

Comment: @JeGad Since  TeX is a Turing-complete language where anyone can define new commands easily, yes, multiple ways are inevitable. But at the end of day this is a great advantage.